# Loss Function in PyTorch where not all my training examples are equally weighted

Tags: python, pytorch, loss

I want to train a Neural Network in PyTorch. I have my training dataset, however I care more about some examples than about others. I want to include this information in the loss function - to let the NN know that it is very important to get some examples right and to not punish errors on other examples very much.
I want to do this by weighting the loss for training examples, let's say:
loss = weight_for_example*(y_true - y_pred)^2
Is there an easy way to do this in PyTorch?

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on your task: for instance, [BCEWithLogitsLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) has a `weight` parameter that allows a custom weight for each batch. Many other built-in losses also provide this option.

Aside from solutions already available in the framework such as this, a simple approach could be the following:

- build a custom dataset, returning your data *and* a scalar weight for that sample in your `__getitem__`
- proceed with the forward pass
- compute your loss, which you can now multiply by the factors you provided.

There's only a caveat (which is the same of the BCELoss): you probably iterate on batches with size > 1, so your dataloader will provide *a batch* of data, with *a batch* of weights. You need to make sure you don't reduce your loss beforehand, so that you can still multiply it by your batch weight, then you can proceed with a manual reduction (e.g. `loss = loss.mean()`).

[See some examples here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/per-class-and-per-sample-weighting/25530).